# Ssh Find 4k video files

Tags: ssh

I have a folder full with video files in sub folders and want to find alls video files that have 4k content and move them I to a separate folder.

Is there a way to find those specific video files over ssh?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. Would you be writing a program to accomplish this? What programming language would you be using?

Comment: Sure I want to use it in a bash script